# Raspberry Pi with TNC-Pi - How to Connect to BBS

Tags: packet

I am brand new to AX25 on a Raspberry Pi with a TNC-Pi and Baofeng UV5R.

I have a BBS at WE1CT-4 which is line of sight at 3 miles. Do I just axcall 1 WE1CT-4. and the BBS will magically appear (if its active)?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have:

- correctly connected your Baofeng to the TNC
- installed the AX25-tools and AX25-apps
- configured /etc/ax25/axports with your call and the baud rate
- attached the serial port to the AX.25 system using kissattach

then you may first want to listen for AX25 traffic on that frequency by typing:

```
 sudo axlisten –a
```

Finally, you can connect to the BBC by typing:

```
 axcall 1 WE1CT-4
```

There should be a short pause and then you will see the splash screen from the BBS.